# PageController not working as State variable

Tags: flutter, dart

When using a `PageController` instantiated within my `State`'s `build` function, my controller is behaving as expected. However, if I make this a variable declared on my `State` itself, I can't seem to get it to work at all.

Works:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _currentPage = 0;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: PageController(initialPage: _currentPage, keepPage: false, viewportFraction: 0.9),
        children: <Widget>[
          SomeWidget(),
          SomeWidget(),
          SomeWidget(),
        ],

      ),

    );
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _currentPage = 0;
  var _pageController;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentPage, keepPage: false, viewportFraction: 0.9);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _pageController,
        children: <Widget>[
          SomeWidget(),
          SomeWidget(),
          SomeWidget(),
        ],

      ),

    );
}
```

With the non-working code, it doesn't even apply the `viewportFraction`, as it does when I instantiate it within the `build` method itself.

What am I missing here? I've compared it to other examples I've found, but maybe I'm missing something that I'm completely oblivious to.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer is apparent after I post!

My mistake was caused by the fact that I assumed my state would be re-initialized after reload when saving my changes. It is not. Re-running my app caused all to be smooth.